# \ref command leads to the caption and not to the figure itself

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, overleaf

when I cite my figures in the text and click on it in the text it shows the caption, not the figure. I have tried \ref{} and it shows the caption

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-image-a}
\caption{Recycled tyre steel fibre (RTSF).}
    \label{FIG:4}
\end{figure}

\newpage\null 

\vfill

\null
\newpage
\ref{FIG:4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{caption}` in your preamble

Comment: See also the hupcap package (oberdiek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `caption` package, the result will be your requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\null
    \newpage
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Recycled tyre steel fibre (RTSF).}
        \label{FIG:4}
\end{figure}
\newpage\null \vfill
\null
\newpage
\ref{FIG:4}
\end{document}
```

Try this code by clicking on the `\ref` command's output.

Comment: Thank you. I am new in using this type of text but ur answer solve the problem.

Comment: Happy TeXing @TalalOAlshammari

Answer (score 1):

[@koleygr's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655283/31283) answer is correct and you should follow his suggestion. Just for demonstration, consider the following code. It artificially creates anchors for `\label{}` via `\refstepcounter{figure}`. Because `\caption{}` used below a figure also adds to the counter, I have to explicitly decrement it before the next figure. The effect is we get referred exactly to that top edge of each image, exactly where the `\refstepcouter{}\label{}` combination is.

`float` solves us from making such cumbersome tricks!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:my_label1}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Image A}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:my_label2}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Image B}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:my_label3}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Image C}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
References: \ref{fig:my_label1}, \ref{fig:my_label2}, \ref{fig:my_label3}.
\end{document}
```

---

Update
Please note, the following example only serves the demonstration. It turns out `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` is not advised in regular documents (see comments).

Comment: caption also loads `capt-of` that saves us from `float` package :) (+1)

Comment: you should not decrement the counter. This will lead to warnings in the pdf `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.3})`, and while in your case the output is ok, it makes it more difficult to handle the problematic cases.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for pointing out the issue. I wasn't aware of that and the answer was written only for demonstration to make anchors at certain locations.

Comment: @Celdor your idea is not wrong, basically it it what one has to do (and what caption and the hypcap do internally) but it needs additional code to handle the details.

Comment: I see. I am afraid that's currently beyond my skills.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the \label command can refer to the graphic itself (as shown if you put your \label before your \caption), so it must refer to the caption. The figure contains both graphic and caption, and probably cannot be referred to without the caption.

However the caption is just below the graphic, so is it such a problem ?

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: `caption` package adds the requested feature ...

Comment: sorry, I am still new and forgot to use the comment.